# Looping a sound in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops, avaudioplayer

I have a rectangle button, when the user presses it once. the sound plays
But I want it so when the user double taps the button, the sound continously loops till the user decided to press to stop the sound.
This is the code to play the sound.

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play]; 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to with Xcode (and it _is_ “Xcode”, not “xCode”). I’mma retag/retitle that for you.

Comment: Lol sorry! Steve Jobs will kill me if he see's this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

The negative value makes the player loop forever until it is stopped.

Comment: Ok how would i controll the speed of the sound its going like the tempo, because the sound is playing really fast

Comment: Add some silence at the end of your wave-file to make the audible repetition slower. (and dont forget to mark Anne's answer as being accepted)